# Row Value Divided By Total Value

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table shown below. I have no issue creating a formula to count the Strike%/Visited. However, if I want to divide it by using the Total Visited by using the measure below, it always returns the same result as in Strike%/Visited.

```
 Strike%/Total Visited = DIVIDE (
     SUM ( Table1[Strike] ),
     CALCULATE (
         SUM ( Table1[Visited] ),
         FILTER (
             Table1
             Table1[year] = "2018"
         )
     ) )
```

[image: DIVIDE by another SUM COLUMN]

Comment: Please format code as code `{}` not as quoted content `>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the filter context in order to get a total.

Try wrapping an `ALL()` or `ALLSELECTED()` function around your first filter argument:

```
Strike%/Total Visited = DIVIDE (
     SUM ( Table1[Strike] ),
     CALCULATE (
         SUM ( Table1[Visited] ),
         FILTER (
             ALL(Table1)
             Table1[year] = "2018"
         )
     ) )
```

Comment: Thanks Alexis, I still need the filter to filter out the records. I put the ALL() unfortunately it still the same. I still trying to figure out how to do it.

Comment: If you need to preserve filters from slicers, then use `ALLSELECTED()` instead.